# A question on Steenbrink's paper, limit of Hodge structures

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry

Steenbrink in his paper ["Limit of Hodge Structures"](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007/BF01403146.pdf), (supplemented by the book "Mixed Hodge Structures" by Peters and Steenbrink) discuss the limit mixed Hodge structures for a fibration over the unit disc $\Delta \subset \mathbb{C}$, i.e. a fibration
$$\pi: X \rightarrow \Delta$$
whose fibers are projective varieties and the only singular fiber is over 0, which is a reduced divisor with smooth normal crossing components.

**Question**: Does Steenbrink's construction in his paper (or book) work in the general case i.e. for a fibration
$$\pi: X \rightarrow \Delta^n$$
I guess this also involves the issues with "simultaneous semi-stable reduction" of this family, which has been discussed in the paper ["A tour of stable reduction with applications"](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1207.1048.pdf).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $\pi$ is semistable, then Fujisawa, *Limits of Hodge structures in several variables. Compositio (1999)*, does this. You might also look at some later papers by the same author for some refinements.

Comment: Thank you very much! In his paper Fujisawa has assumed semi-stable of the family. For base space of dimension greater than one, (currently) there is no semi-stable reduction theorem like the dimension one case. I am curious what are the obstructions?

Comment: Fujisawa has a sequel to the Compositio paper: https://arxiv.org/abs/1506.02271